# Fireworks CS3 crashes when I try to open it on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, crash, adobe-fireworks

I've just installed Win 7 and the CS3 web premium collection. Its pretty much a clean install ( about a week old ), but for some reason every time I open Fireworks it crashes with the error 'The application Fireworks has unexpectedly quit'.

Photoshop, dreamweaver & Illustrator work fine, seems odd that its just Fireworks.

I've tried a reinstall from the disk, is there anything else I can try? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have also been having this problem. 
Fireworks worked after I installed it, but a few days later stopped working. Logging in with another user made it work.

I have spent 10 minutes going through the registry and have found the problem in my case.

One of the sites in here.... 
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Adobe\Common\9\Sites

was obviously corrupted or invalid, because removing it allowed fireworks to load up again!

If there is someone from Adobe that would like to see the registry information I removed so they can bug check it then I have saved the offending site entry, or if anyone knows where I can send it, since this seems to be a fairly common problem.

I hope this information helps

Comment: This was the problem! I removed the site fom the definitions and it loaded fine. As soon as I added it again it crashed. I narrowed it down to removing the space from the site definition name, and that sorted it. Its a definite common bug and it would be good to see some feedback from Adobe on this issue.

Answer (score -2):

Eh, fireworks doesnt crash INSTANTLY for me; (im using the portable version) But when i try to save, no dialog boxes come up, and it also crashes at any random point it feels like with no prior warning. The only solution I have is downgrading to Windows XP, Fireworks always ran totally fine on my old CPU. Or, you could try using a windows emulator to emulate the actual Windows XP environment on your PC; that may fix it. NOTE: Windows XP Emulators are ILLEGAL unless you actually own a copy of Windows XP, so beware.