# Adobe Master Collection CS3 wont run on my Windows 7 64bit

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, adobe-cs3

I have a brand new HP p6230y.  My first step after booting it up was to install Master Collection.  It installs fine, but when I go to run each of the applications, and they all behave differently. I have re-installed twice already.

Photoshop opens, but freezes.
Acrobat tells me that I need to reinstall.
Nothing else even opens (no freezing, no process in taskman).

Any Ideas?

**HP p6230y**

- RAM: 8gigs
- CPU: AMD Phenom2 x4 810
  (2.6ghz)
- OS: Windows 7 Home Ultimate
  64bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried XP mode? (I know, I know, less RAM in virtualized OS's)

Try using "running as" as an older version of windows. (Right click> properties)

Remember, these programs are only certified  for 32-bit OS's.

Also, before reinstalling, uninstall completely and clear the temporary files and low-level licensing files.

Comment: Trying it now, hopefully I can give you 10 points when this works :).

Answer (score 1):

Did you update the programs after installation?

There are several hundred megabytes of updates for CS3. After a round of updates, reboot, and then check for updates again. Repeat this process until all updates are installed.

I have CS3 Design Premium on Windows 7 Pro (64-bit) and it seems to be running flawlessly since November - But, I'm missing a lot of what's in the Master Collection.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to see this question:

[Fireworks CS3 crashes when I try to open it on Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/70044/fireworks-cs3-crashes-when-i-try-to-open-it-on-windows-7)

Additionally CS3 uses your graphics card to perform functions, might be worth ensuring you have the latest drivers in-case some sort of start-up check is causing the issue